# Strange battery behavior after updating from 14.04 to 15.04

Tags: 15.04, laptop, power-management, battery

I'm using HP machine with Intel Pentium N3520 and 4GB RAM. I recently updated to Ubuntu 15.04 and facing issues with battery, which is behaving like anything. It does not charges when operating system is on and remain stuck, which means I'm charging battery after putting the machine off. I've tried multiple things but it is not working. I don't want to give up on Ubuntu as it is Linux based.